# Yocto bitbake error: Nothing Provides for 'recipe-name'

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe in one of the meta layer. Its structure is given below:

```
meta-custom/swupdate/recipes-extended/images/recipe-name.bb
```

meta-custom layer is also included in the bblayers.conf. But when I run bitbake recipe-name I get the below error:

```
Bitbake error: Nothing PROVIDES for 'recipe-name'. Closes matches:
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added `meta-custom` to your `bblayers.conf`?

Comment: As mentioned above, meta-custom layer is already present in bblayers.conf

Comment: move `recipes-extended` one layer up, to `meta-custom`.

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr, Can you please let me know why moving one layer up will solve this issue?

Comment: In a not-so-related case, I ran into this error when I have a change in meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/perfetto in my local copy of meta-openembedded and was creating a symbolic link from it to the meta-openembedded folder of the specific Yocto build I'm building. Making a "real" copy of the perfetto folder rather than a symbolic link helped avoid the "nothing PROVIDES" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: in your local.conf, add this:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " recipe-name "
```

Be sure to include the spaces in " recipe-name ", otherwise you may run into errors where your recipe isn't separated from others, e.g. ERROR nothing provides "someOtherRecipeyourrecipe-name"

Long answer: Disregarding local.conf, within your own layer (if applicable), you may have a distro configuration file within conf/distro/distro.conf (or whatever you named it). This can act as your local.conf, and is more sought after for maintained yocto layers. Within that, you would add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " recipe-name "
```

just as you would in your local.conf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the recipe is generating output packages that
are not names same as recipe.

bitbake recipe-name -e | egrep ^PACKAGES

Answer (score 0):

Just try -
$ bitbake imagename          - DO NOT INCLUDE .bb extension